# How to create a kendoComboBox with dynamically named event functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

Let's say I have a java script to add a dynamically created kendoComboBox

A placeholder HTML input with type text or hidden box gets previously created with an ID=cbId, where cbId is the Id assigned to the Html text input box.

```
var cbId = "comboBoxId";
<input type="hidden" id="\" + cbId + "\" />
```

Then the placeholder input Text element gets converted into a kendoComboBox by calling this function:

```
function OP_createComboBox(cbId, placeholder, dataTextField, dataValueField, dataSource, selectFunction ) {
    console.log(" * Creating non-cascading ComboBox...");
    $("#" + cbId).kendoComboBox({
        Name: cbId,
        id: cbId,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        dataTextField: dataTextField,
        dataValueField: dataValueField,
        filter: "contains",
        suggest: true,
        dataSource: dataSource,
        select: onFubarSelect
        });
}
```

When a item is selected in the comboBox, the onFubar functions gets called with a event argument.
Say the onFubar function is defined as follows:

```
function onFubarSelect(e) {
    console.log("== onFubarSelect(e=>%o<=) STARTS!! ==", e);
    console.log("* e.item.index()=>%o<=", e.item.index());
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    console.log("* dataItem=>%o<=", dataItem);
    OP_consoleLog("* dataItem.<dataTextField>=>%o<=", dataItem.<dataTextField>);

    //do more logic based upon the values of <dataTextField> and <dataValueField>

    OP_consoleLog("== onFubarSelect() ENDS ==");
}
```

When the page readers and an Item is selected from the kendoComboBox, the onFubarSelect gets called and
console.log("* dataItem=>%o<=", dataItem); will print out something simular to this:

(below "VV" denotes an "expanded object" down arrow, and ">>" represents an "unexpanded object" right arrow)

```
== onFubarSelect(e=> VV Object
                                    _defaultPrevented: false
                                    >> isDefaultPrevented: ()
                                    >> item: R.fn.init[1]
                                    >>preventDefault: ()
                                    >>sender: init
                                    >>__proto__: Object<=) STARTS!! 
<= STARTS!! ==

* e.item.index()=>1<=

* dataItem=> VV init                                          <=    
                <dataValueField>: "35dcffc5-e31d-4c60-ac41-31417a700d3b"
                <dataTextField>: "The Value associated with the above Guid"
                >>_events: Object
                >>_handlers: Object
                >>parent: ()
                uid: "f1f1b5c1-f155-40c3-8f69-d9b4a960ac15"
                >>__proto__: init

* dataItem.<dataTextField>=>"The Value associated with the above Guid"<=

== onFubarSelect() ENDS ==
```

**The above is the desired behavior.**

So far all well and good.
But I don't want to hardcode the select argument to onFubarSelect:

```
$("#" + cbId).kendoComboBox({
    Name: cbId,
    ...
    select: onFubarSelect
    });
```

Rather I want to set it dynamically.

I tried something like below, but it reports "Uncaught TypeError: r[n].call is not a function"...

```
var selectFunction = "onFubarSelect";

$("#" + cbId).kendoComboBox({
    Name: cbId,
    ...
    select: selectFunction
    });
```

Then I tried something like below:

```
var selectFunction = "onFubarSelect";

$("#" + cbId).kendoComboBox({
    Name: cbId,
    ...
    function (e) { window[selectFunction](e); }
    });
```

Where the selectFunction gets called, but the 'this.dataItem' gives an error:

```
== onFubarSelect(e=> VV Object
                                    _defaultPrevented: false
                                    >> isDefaultPrevented: ()
                                    >> item: R.fn.init[1]
                                    >>preventDefault: ()
                                    >>sender: init
                                    >>__proto__: Object<=) STARTS!! 
<= STARTS!! ==

* e.item.index()=>1<=

>> Uncaught TypeError: this.dataItem is not a function
        at onFubarSelect
        ...
        rest of stack trace
        ...
```

I also tried:

```
...
select: select: function (e) { eval(selectFunction + "(e)"); } 
...
```

Which hits also the function with an argument, but again leaves the 'this.dataItem' with the same "this.dataItem is not a function" error.

**So how can I dynamically set the select event dynamically so the "this.dataItem" is preserved???**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is the `call` method. It allows you to define what `this` is when executing a function. Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 0):

What I found to work was to use the following for my select action:

```
var selectFunction = "onFubarSelect";

...
$("#" + cbId).kendoComboBox({
   Name: cbId,
   ...
   select: function (e) {
      var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
      window[selectFunction](dataItem);            
   }
});
```

...
...
...

```
function onFubarSelect(dataItem) {
   console.log("== onFubarSelect(dataItem=>%o<=) STARTS!! ==", dataItem);
   //do more logic based upon information in dataItem...
}
```